# RewriteRule when transferring files from root to another directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Previously, a lot of project files was in the the root directory. Including the following files was in the root:

```
index.php
make.php
```

In order to make file structure more logical, the above files have been moved to the /operation/ folder.

Question: how to write a redirect rule in .htaccess if I want the following links to still work correctly:

```
https://example.com/ 
https://example.com/?var=value 
https://example.com/make.php
```

And so that the client does not even guess that, in fact, the access goes to files:

```
https://example.com/operation/
https://example.com/operation/?var=value
https://example.com/operation/make.php
```

If I specify rules like this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /operation/
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php)$ /operation/$1
```

then https://example.com/ works normally, but https://example.com/make.php does not work.

Comment: Have you tried this? `RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.php$ /operation/$1`

Answer (score 0):

The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash in per-directory `.htaccess` files, so the regex `^/(.*\.php)$` never matches and the request is not rewritten.

However, your question text states 3 URLs that need to be rewritten, but the code you've posted looks like it is intended to match "any" `.php` file. Is that the intention? Or would this conflict with other `.php` files in the root directory?

> ```
> https://example.com/ 
> https://example.com/?var=value 
> https://example.com/make.php
> ```

To rewrite these 3 URLs, you would do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /operation/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(make\.php)$ /operation/$1 [L]
```

You should rewrite directly to the file that handles the request, ie. `index.php` in the first rule. Otherwise, you are reliant on mod_dir issuing an additional internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex. The first rule catches both requests for `/` and `/index.php`. The query string is passed through by default.

Don't forget the `L` flag, otherwise, processing continues (unnecessarily).

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /operation/$1 [NC]
```